# What happened with Magento 2 Service Layer?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

As far as I remember, there were a lot of talks about importance of Magento 2 Service Layer and many services with different methods we had out of the box. When I downloaded the latest build, I was noticed that a lot of services were gone. For example, the built in **CatalogInventory** module has a service where you were able to collect different data. The service is still described in the official wiki: http://goo.gl/A7mVr8. But currently the method `getProductStockStatusBySku()` was moved from the service to the model and the service was completely removed. The same situation with many other built in modules.
The Magento Service Layer philosophy/purpose has changed?

Comment: I'll let someone else from the team give a full answer, but I believe that only the Customer module is even close to being functionally adapted to M2 architecture at this point. Other modules follow after Dev Beta is concluded in March.

Comment: I was thinking the same way. However, the core dev team removed the most of logic from the service layer back to the trivial places. It looks like a sort of step back

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's now in the Api directory rather than Service directory. It has not gone away! There are a few blog posts on [alankent.wordpress.com](http://alankent.wordpress.com/) as well if helpful.

Also official Magento 2 documentation has moved to [devdocs.magento.com](http://devdocs.magento.com/). The wiki tends to get found in searches first and has not been taken down yet. Short term solution in google is to add site:devdocs.magento.com as a search term for now.